# SonarLint cannot connect to SonarQube Server

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, lint

I have eclipse mars2 with sonarLint 2.1.
I try to connect to a SonarQube Server 5.1.2

When I try to connect via the eclipse GUI, the following error occurs:

The following plugins do not meet the required minimum versions, please upgrade them: java (installed: 3.0, minimum: 3.8)

Do you have any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The plugin the message is referring to is the Sonar Java Plugin. Log in to Sonar as admin, go to Administration/System/Update Center and you'll see that the current installed plugin version is 3.0. Update it to the newest version available and it should work.

[Edit] - The upgrade is triggered by just clicking the button, but after it is downloaded and installed, you'll have to restart the Sonar server.

Comment: Manual update is also possible https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+a+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to downgrade to an older version of the plugin:

1. Exit IntelliJ
2. Delete the files in the following folder (your version of Idea may be in a slightly different folder
   C:\Users\USER.IdeaIC2018.1\config\plugins\SonarLint\lib
3. Download version 3.5.1.2759 from the following: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint
4. Unzip all the files from the downloaded file to the above folder

Comment: This question is about the Eclipse plugin, not IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

The newest available version in the update centre is 3.14 for some reasons.
Anybody has been able to install the 3.8?

Comment: Why would someone upgrade it from 3.0 to 3.8 instead of the newest 3.14? Please note that the current version is 3.14, not the same as 3.1.4 (3.14 > 3.8 while 3.1.4 < 3.8). For more informations about the versions check http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin (clicking on the "More versions" button).

Comment: Because I had another plugin not compatible with the newest version of the Java plugin. All sorted now, thank you!